# passing variable from view file to another view file

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I would like to get variable available from a view file to another view after loading it in Codeigniter. Suppose, I have a code snippet in a view file name example.php

`$test = 'test'`

And I load this view file in test.php like this

$this->load->view('example.php') after this in test.php I would like to get the value of the variable $test in test.php view file

Comment: try ajax to do that

Answer (score 1):

I have able to resolve the issues using $GLOBALS

Answer (score 0):

Just pass

```
$data = ['test' => $test];
```

to like

```
$this->load->view('example.php', $data);
```

Comment: The same we we passed data to example.php we have to pass data to test.php